# Unity: Resources.Load is not working

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, resources, assets

```
string filePath = "hfba_25";
TextAsset textAsset = Resources.Load(filePath) as TextAsset;
string fileString = textAsset.text;
```

I cant seem to figure it out why the resources wont load not in the editor and also not on a android device? The file `hfba_25` is in the folder `Assets > Resources > hfba_25`

Edit_1: textAsset is always returned as `NULL`

Comment: What "does not work" ? Have you any error message ? What do you get in the`fileString` variable ?

Comment: @Hellium nothing i get textAsset as null with no other error messages

Comment: Do you check if your file format is supported? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `textAsset` is always `null`, it can mean two things (due to your code):

1. The file `hfba_25` doesn't exist in the `Resources` subdir;
2. The file does exist, but can't be cast as a `TextAsset`.

To check which of the two is true, you need to change the code to this:

```
TextAsset textAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(filePath);
Debug.Log(textAsset);
```

then run inside Unity and check the console.

If you just get `Null`, then it means that it's 1 (file doesn't exist).

If instead you get `InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`, then it means it's 2, the file exists but it can't be cast as a `TextAsset` type.

This happens because in C#, if you cast using the keyword `as`, when the cast is invalid you don't get an exception, but instead the reference is just set to `null`.

Comment: Yup, you are right. The json files are saving as Type:File in windows and not as Type:json. Thanks man/woman.