Trying to create a json file to store some data but when trying to acces it : NullReferenceException
I'm working on a rubiks cube algorithm trainer project on unity  and I'm trying to create json files to store different collections of algorithms.
When I create the file i immediatly try to update my collections but I then get a NullReferenceException.
Here is all the code that is related to my issue.
public void AddCollection(string collectionName)
{
    string tempPath = new string(path + "/" + collectionName + ".txt");
    if (!File.Exists(tempPath))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(tempPath, GetBaseFileCollection(collectionName));
    }
    algManager.UpdateCollections();
    UpdateDropDown();
}

public string GetBaseFileCollection(string collectionName)
{
    string temp = "{\r\n\t\"collectionName\" : \"" + collectionName + "\"\r\n}";
    return temp;
}

//algManager
public void UpdateCollections()
{
    algorithms.Clear();
    info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var fileInfo = info.GetFiles("*.txt");
    foreach (FileInfo file in fileInfo)
    {
        var textFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(file.Name.Replace(".txt", ""));
        algorithms.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlgorithmCollection>(textFile.text)); 
        //the error occurs on this line ^
}

And here is my AlgorithmCollection class that the json files deserializes into
public class AlgorithmCollection
{
    public string collectionName;

    [SerializeField]
    public List<AlgorithmBase> algorithms;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class AlgorithmBase
{
    public string algorithmName;

    public List<string> algorithm;

    public int cubeSize;

    [SerializeField]
    public List<Mover.Face> tilesColor;
}

I tried using VS2022 debug function and when entering the foreach UpdateCollection i do have the file but var textFile is null after Resources.Load.

On the line that is throwing the error, there are three possible things that can be null.

algorithms
textFile
textFile.text

Since algorithms.Clear(); is called earlier and does not throw a null reference exception, it has to be either textFile or textFile.text.
What does the debugger say is null?

it says : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
AlgorithmManager.UpdateCollections () (at Assets/Scripts/AlgorithmManager.cs:37)

That is not the debugger, that is the trace from the exception. Please enter the debugger, and view the autos/locals to determine what is null. Place a breakpoint before the function, and once you are inside the function. Once you hit that line of code it will show you the exact values of what each declared variable is.

So in the foreach loop, the FileInfo file is the created file but the var textFile is null when using Resources.Load

From the documentation here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html
This method returns the asset at path if it can be found, otherwise it returns null.
Note that the path is case insensitive and must not contain a file extension. All asset names and paths in Unity use forward slashes, so using backslashes in the path will not work.
Make sure that path is valid, try printing out the entire filepath including the system path to see if the file is located correctly there. Also, looks like you are replacing the file extension here? Why? The file structure will need it.

The thing is IF i do all these steps when i hit play and the new file was already created then there is no problem but if i hit play then create the file and try to access it it, the error occurs.
And I'm replacing the file extention otherwise it's just not working from what i saw on that method it only needs the file name thus the name with the extension makes it non existent for the method

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691706/unity-resources-load-is-not-working
Top answer here may help you here. Follow the cast steps to see if it truly cannot find it.

I found a solution, i just needed to refresh the folder to get the file content so instead of Resources.Load i used AssetDatabse.LoadAssetAtPath to get the content and AssetDatabse.Refresh just before. Still thank you very much for your efforts and your help

I just needed to refresh the folder before getting the .json files content so I changed the Resources.Load method to AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath and used AssetDatabase.Refresh before the foreach loop.
